# How to capture image from camera and upload to Retrofit multipart?

Tags: android, image, upload, retrofit2, multipart

I am doing the following to capture image from camera and upload it to web service through retrofit multipart image upload, but i am facing problem in converting bitmap to image file to be able to fill the image file multipart parameter of the retrofit web service call. I have used URI to convert bitmap from camera to file and i am getting null pointer exception in that function.

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        final Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
        Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getActivity(), photo);

        // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
        File file = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

        MyWebService webService =
                MyWebService.retrofit.create(MyWebService.class);

        MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));

        Call<com.syamantak.footsteps.models.response.Response> call = webService.set_profile_photo(filePart, "Bearer " + MainActivity.api_token);
        MainActivity.setProgressBarVisible();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<com.syamantak.footsteps.models.response.Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<com.syamantak.footsteps.models.response.Response> call, Response<com.syamantak.footsteps.models.response.Response> response) {
                MainActivity.setProgressBarInVisible();
                com.syamantak.footsteps.models.response.Response jsonResponse = response.body();
                selfieImage.setImageBitmap(photo);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), jsonResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<com.syamantak.footsteps.models.response.Response> call, Throwable t) {
                t.getLocalizedMessage();
            }
        });
    }
}


public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    String path = "";
    if (getActivity().getContentResolver() != null) {
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
            path = cursor.getString(idx);
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

Following is my manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.syamantak.footsteps">

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I am getting following error

```
E/MediaStore: Failed to insert image
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=28108, uid=10237 requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
```

and

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=67424, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.syamantak.footsteps/com.syamantak.footsteps.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I arrived at following solution

```
        final Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        File file = savebitmap(photo);

        MyWebService webService =
                MyWebService.retrofit.create(MyWebService.class);

        MultipartBody.Part filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photo", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file));

        Call<com.syamantak.footsteps.models.response.Response> call = webService.set_profile_photo(filePart, "Bearer " + MainActivity.api_token);
        MainActivity.setProgressBarVisible();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<com.syamantak.footsteps.models.response.Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<com.syamantak.footsteps.models.response.Response> call, Response<com.syamantak.footsteps.models.response.Response> response) {
                MainActivity.setProgressBarInVisible();
                com.syamantak.footsteps.models.response.Response jsonResponse = response.body();
                selfieImage.setImageBitmap(photo);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), jsonResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<com.syamantak.footsteps.models.response.Response> call, Throwable t) {
                t.getLocalizedMessage();
            }
        });
```

and following function to convert bitmap to file

```
private File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    // String temp = null;
    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "temp.png");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
        file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "temp.png");

    }

    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return file;
}
```

It is working well.

Answer (score -1):

**If you want to send image with more different parameters in Multipart/formData then use this below code. It will solve your Problem.**

```
    ` **1) Put this line above onCreate() method.**

    File selectedFile = null;
    
    **2) In onActivityResult() method of Camera Intent put this below code -**

    final Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(photo);
                selectedFile = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "image" + ".jpg");
                FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
                try {
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(selectedFile);
                    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


**3) In API Interface Class -**

 @Multipart
    @POST("photouploadWithdata.php")
    Call<YourResponseModal> startDuty(@PartMap HashMap<String, RequestBody> map, @Part MultipartBody.Part image);


**4) In Activity when you call API-** 

 RequestBody tokens = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), token);
        RequestBody dates = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), date);
        RequestBody times = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), time);
        RequestBody latitudes = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), latitude);
        RequestBody longitudes = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), longitude);


        MultipartBody.Part image = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("avatar", selectedFile.getName(),
                RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(selectedFile.getName())), selectedFile));

        HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("token", tokens);
        map.put("date", dates);
        map.put("time_in", times);
        map.put("latitude", latitudes);
        map.put("longitude", longitudes);

        RetrofitAPI retrofitAPI = APIClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(RetrofitAPI.class);
        Call<StartDutyResponseModal> call = retrofitAPI.startDuty(map, image);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<StartDutyResponseModal>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<StartDutyResponseModal> call, Response<StartDutyResponseModal> response) {
                if (response.body().getStatus() == true){
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(StartDutyActivity.this, StoreListActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

                else {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    AppUtils.showToast(response.body().getMessage(), StartDutyActivity.this);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<StartDutyResponseModal> call, Throwable t) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                AppUtils.showToast(t.getMessage(),StartDutyActivity.this);
            }
        });
    }

`
```